# Blind an element and change style css at same tyme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my portfolio and need help to #blind an element and change style property at bottom element at same time.

The idea is to exist a fixed space between the two elements, like this one [EXAMPLE](http://r-ny.com)

If u see the example when you click, a bar appears and the space between two remains. Then if u click again the element hide and the space remains the same!!

"#contacts" -> element i want to blind

"#line" -> element i want change the top property

Im trying to resolve using jquery function called "blind":

```
   $("#contacts").toggle("blind", {direction : "vertical"}, 500);
```

Then i get the top value of #line with if:

```
   var line = $( "#line" ); 
   var  position = line.position(); 
   var top = position.top;
   if(top == value){
   $("#line").animate({top:'100px'}, time);
   } else { ... }
```

Please help!!

Comment: Does your console give any errors? You do realize you need to import jQuery and jQuery UI for this to work, correct? Can you provide a demo of *your* code?

Comment: No errors! I already resolve it but not works properly good. If i click twice the space crash [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/949hT/3/)

Comment: You are getting an error... `Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function `

Comment: yes but this isn't me problem " Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function jquery-1.10.2.js:9216 "

Comment: Do you now any framework i can use or any other solution?

Comment: I posted an answer with how I'd do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it without jQuery UI by using the `top` value and `z-index`

```
var contactTop = 85,
    nextTop;
$(".oppen").click(function() {
        nextTop = nextTop !== contactTop ? contactTop : 5;
        $("#contacts").animate({top: nextTop}, 500);
    .....
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/949hT/4/)

To stop the queuing you can apply the same technique on `#line` in addition to using jQuery's `.stop`

```
var contactTop = 85,
    nextTop,
    lineStart = 100,
    lineEnd = 180,
    lineTop = 100;
$(".oppen").click(function() {
    nextTop = nextTop !== contactTop ? contactTop : 5;
    $("#contacts").stop().animate({top: nextTop}, 500);
    lineTop = lineTop !== lineStart ? lineStart : lineEnd;
    $( "#line" ).stop().animate({top:lineTop}, 500);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/949hT/5/)

Comment: One more question. If you click twice very quickly at the button the transition crash, I mean the box goes up but line remains down

Comment: @rm596 Updated with a fix for the queuing. And how do you know me? :)

Comment: i understand ur solution!! change z index in nav and apply 2 animates